# How do I convert an ISO 8601 Datetime to a string?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a datetime from youtube's API:

```
uploadTime = item.snippet.publishedAt;
```

it represents the time that a youtube video was published at, and it is in ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ).

How do I convert this into a string?

I've already tried `toISOString()`, but that doesn't work.

Comment: ISO 8601 already is a string format. Do you want to convert it into a different string representation?

Comment: @GregHewgill Hmm.. I didn't know this... but it will not let me split the data at the "T" (to have [0] = date, and [1] = time). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Sure, the `T` always occurs in the same place in an ISO 8601 string. Use [String.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or something to extract each half.

Comment: What do you mean by "*I have a date + time*"? Do you have a string? Do you have a `Date` object? Some example code would help a lot!

Comment: @Bergi I'll add the code to the original post, give me 30 seconds :)

Comment: What happens whens when you call `uploadTime.toISOString()`? What does `console.log(uploadTime)` print in your console?

Comment: You can always do `new Date("<iso 8601 string here>")` to get a _real_ date. From there on you can search how to convert that date to other representations. There are many questions about that in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @m4ktub: …except in older browsers that don't support ISO 8601 format for dates :-/

Comment: @Bergi There are so many adapters, polyfills, and the likes out there that sometimes I forget. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Youtube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems):

> `snippet.publishedAt`
>   *datetime*:
>   The date and time that the item was added to the playlist. The value is specified in ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sZ) format.

It should already be in ISO 8601 format. If not, just parse it and call `.toISOString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var isoDate = new Date(uploadTime).toISOString();
```

Comment: Wow that seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: @LewisHarris did you check whether `uploadTime` was already in ISO format? According to the youtube API, the above is redundant, since it should already hand you an ISO-8601-valid string. You should really tell us what `console.log(uploadTime)` prints.

Comment: This makes no sense. Isn't this just the identity function?

Comment: Oh wait... I don't think this is the answer, I changed the variable name and re-wrote the function it was used in and it fixed it for real. Must have been a spelling mistake.